# count the total number of keys from nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, nested

I have a nested object with different types of properties including string, object and array. I used the recursive approach to count the total number of keys (from key1 to key9) in the object, but failed to achieve the correct solution. Example of my code below.

```
const data = {
  key1: '1',
  key2: '2',
  key3: { key4: '4' },
  key5: [
    {
      key6: '6',
      key7: '7',
    },
    {
      key8: '8',
      key9: '9',
    }
  ]
}

const countKeys = (data) => {
  let count = 0;

  const helper = (data) => {
    for (let value of Object.values(data)) {
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        helper(value);
      }
      // this line is problematic as it counts each object in the array as key. 
      if (!Array.isArray(value)) count++;
    }
  }
  helper(data)
  return count;
}
console.log(countKeys(data)) // 10, correct answer is 9
```

I try to wrap my head around for many hours but couldn't get the solution. Can anyone explain me what I'm missing here and supposed to add to make it work?

Comment: hi, perhaps use `Object.keys`

Comment: How exactly do you get to 10? If you magically don't count array indices, i'd see 9, otherwise, 11.

Comment: Just wonder what exactly do you want to count? The 9 count all the item from `key1` to `key9`

Comment: @jspacal I don't think Object.keys would work when we get to 'key5' which has array property?

Comment: @ASDFGerte actually there was a typo. Correct answer should be 9, but i was getting 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data provided, there are nine (9) keys. You could use a recursive `countKeys(t)` and do a type analysis on `t`'s type -

1. When it's an Object, for all `v` in `Object.values(t)`, reduce and count one plus the recursive result, `countKeys(v)`
2. When it's an Array, for all `v` in `t`, sum `countKeys(v)`
3. Otherwise `t` is neither an Object nor an Array, return zero

```js
function countKeys(t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Object:                                     // 1
      return Object
        .values(t)
        .reduce((r, v) => r + 1 + countKeys(v), 0)
    case Array:                                      // 2
      return t
        .reduce((r, v) => r + countKeys(v), 0)
    default:                                         // 3
      return 0
  }
}

const data =
  {key1:"1",key2:"2",key3:{key4:"4"},key5:[{key6:"6",key7:"7"},{key8:"8",key9:"9"}]}

console.log(countKeys(data))
```